# How to create horizontal lines on the side with a circle between them

Tags: html, css

i want to draw like this with css and made it with different methods but it is not responsive and something went wrong can anyone help me to do it

i did it at last like this but also something went wrong

Comment: Hi rosafa, welcome to SO! Can you put a code snippet in your question to help us along?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Show us what you have tried and describe what goes wrong, not just ‘something went wrong’. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ? If yes.. there you go ^^

```css
#container {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.line {
  background-color: black;
  height: 2px;
  width: 50px;
}

#circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div id="circle"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you this helped alot but how can i make it responsive it moves from its place in other screens